# call further validators from isValid() method?

Tags: java, bean-validation

suppose i have the following scenario:

```
public class EntityA {
   private List<EntityB> listOfBs;
}
```

im trying to cascade validation to the list of Bs only if running under a certain validation group. so ideally, this:

```
public class EntityA {
   @Valid(groups = {SomeSpecificGroup.class})
   private List<EntityB> listOfBs;
}
```

unfortunately, @Valid does not have a groups() property. so i figured i'd try something like:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = { CascadedValidator.class })
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CascadedValidation {
    Class<?>[] groups() default { };
}
```

and write a validator (CascadedValidator) that upon activation will do the cascade (==will validate all elements of the collection its placed on).
my issue is how do i perform the cascaded validation? 
so far i have this:

```
public class CascadedValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CascadedValidation, Object>{
    private Class<?>[] groups;

    @Override public void initialize(CascadedValidation constraintAnnotation) {
        groups = constraintAnnotation.groups();
    }

    @Override public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value == null || !(value instanceof Iterable)) {
            return true;
        }
        for (Object item : (Iterable)value) {
            //validate item using the groups?!
        }
    }
}
```

i know i could implement the actual validation by creating another Validator "inline":

```
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations;
if (decideIfCascade(groups)) {
    for (Object item : (Iterable)value) {
        if (groups!=null && groups.length>0) {
            violations = validator.validate(item, groups);
        } else {
            violations = validator.validate(item);
        }
        if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return true;
```

but this just smells bad to me.
surely there's a sane/normal/easy way of doing this?

**EDIT - the actual use case**

my API accept both EntityA (which has a list of Bs) and EntityB as top-level entities (so you can send a single B directly). both A and B have an id property, but i only require a non-null id on the top level object submitted. so if the service gets an A with an idea and several "blank" Bs its ok, but if i get a B as a top level parameter it must have an id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not invoke the validation engine from within a `ConstraintValidator` implementation.

If you are on Bean Validation 1.1, have a look at [group conversions](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-groupsequence-groupconversion) which give you control over the validation groups propagated upon cascaded validation. E.g. you could do the following:

```
@Valid
@ConvertGroup(from = Default.class, to = SomeSpecificGroup.class)
private List<EntityB> listOfBs;
```

Comment: when you say "should not" - is it explicitely forbidden or just plain ugly? also i cant use convertgroup. i've elaborated on my question above to explain why. i dont want to somehow "spin" the cascade, i want to block it altogether

Comment: It's not explicitly forbidden, but it's a) a potential performance issue (at least if you create a new validator factory which needs to build up the constraint meta-model again) and b) you may run into an infinite loop if there are bi-directional relationships in your model and you're using `@Valid` (a single validator needs to make sure it prevents infinite loops).

Comment: That being said, I think you actually can use `@ConvertGroup`, just convert `Default` to any other group on the cascaded member. The `@NotNull` constraint in B will then be validated when it is on the top-level but not when navigating from A.